# How to get bold title of the reference when using natbib plainnat?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I use in the `report` class literature like this (simplified):

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[
  pagebackref=true,
  breaklinks=true,
  colorlinks=true,
  bookmarks=true,
  pdfencoding=auto,
  unicode=true,
  xetex
  ]{hyperref}
...
\usepackage[round, semicolon, authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
...
\bibliography{literature}
...
```

No other extra special settings. I like the look of the bibliography, with the only change: I'd like to have the title of the referenced work printed in bold in the biobliography. Is this (easily) possible?

[image: How to get bold title in the bibliography?]

Comment: I have removed the tags irrelevant for your question (you are using `natbib` and so you can't be using the alternative, but incompatible `biblatex`, XeTeX has nothing to do with the formatting of the bibliography in general, ...). You'll probably have to hack `plainnat.bst` to get bold titles.

Comment: Please note that your code snippet does not constitute a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Your question is already fairly clear without a fully compilable example, but it makes the lives of those who are willing to help just a tad easier to not just post some code, but *fully compilable* code. Do you want all titles in bold, or only those of `@article`s, or something even more fancy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the format of `@article` `title`s, you'll have to modify the `.bst` file directly.

1. Locate `plainnat.bst` on your machine. You can do this by typing `kpsewhich plainnat.bst` into the command line/terminal. Alternatively, obtain a copy of the file from CTAN http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/plainnat.bst
2. Copy the file to a location where TeX can find it. The document directory will do fine.
3. Rename the file to `plainnat-bftitle.bst`
4. Open the file and replace the block starting with `FUNCTION {format.title}` (ll. 299-304 in my version) by

   ```
   FUNCTION {format.title}
   { title empty$
       { "" }
       { "\textbf{" title "t" change.case$ * "}" * }
     if$
   }
   ```

   The only change is in the fourth line.
5. Add your name and date and explain the modification in the comments at the top of the file.
6. Use `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-bftitle}` instead of `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` in your document.

With the new file

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[round, semicolon, authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat-bftitle}

\begin{document}
\cite{doody,sarfraz,moore}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]